# npm: install and use different versions of a package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, installation

Is there a way to install and also **use** the different package versions in `npm`? Installations works:

```
npm install -g packagename@2.8
npm install -g packagename@3.1
npm install -g packagename@4.0
```

I can install `npm install -g web3@0.20.7` and check `npm view web3 versions` them. But how can I **use** them in the `*.js` script? Something like this:

```
require('packagename@2.8');
require('packagename@3.1');
require('packagename@4.0');
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a node module that allows you to do it.

```
npm-install-version
```

Install it: `npm install npm-install-version --save-dev`

```
var niv = require('npm-install-version');

niv.install('packagenameolder@1.0.0');
niv.install('packagenamenewer@1.0.1');

var package_old = niv.require('packagenameolder@1.0.0');
var package_new = niv.require('packagenamenewer@1.0.1');
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks useful, but the last update was 2 years ago. Is this still the way to go and also compatible with the new node/npm versions?

Comment: I am not sure about compatible with latest npm version. You can go for yarn if you want.

Comment: like==>  yarn add alias-for-package@npm:packagename@version

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and it seems that its not possible with standard NPM. Here is the feature-request: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/5499

However, with `yarn` (an NPM alternative from Facebook), you can do it out of the box by using `yarn add` and giving the package an [alias](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/cli/add/#toc-yarn-add-alias).

I have not tried this for globally installed packages though, I assume it works the same.